# Gridview Footer Button Disbale it show Error as Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hai every one  i am new to asp.net. my question is i  have gridview with textboxs in itemtempleates and single button in footer.when i  click that button in gridview rows are added manually, and ny coding is

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         onselectedindexchanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged">
         <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="S.No" DataField="RowNumber" />
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox132" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SMV">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox133" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="O/L">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox134" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="F/L">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox135" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S/N">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox136" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Helper">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox137" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Man Power">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox138" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                  <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                 <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add New" 
                         onclick="Button1_Click1" />
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

         </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

This is my front end coding....

And aspx.cs coding is

```
 public void bindgrid()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column5", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column6", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column7", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column4"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column5"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column6"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column7"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //dr = dt.NewRow();

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        int val = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox63.Text);
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox132");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox133");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox134");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox135");
                    TextBox box5 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox136");
                    TextBox box6 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("TextBox137");
                    TextBox box7 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox138");
                    Button btn = this.GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("btnFooter") as Button;


                        drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                        drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;


                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column4"] = box4.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column5"] = box5.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column6"] = box6.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column7"] = box7.Text;

                        rowIndex++;
                        **if (rowIndex+1 > val)
                        {
                            btn.Visible = false;
                        }**
                    }

                    {
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);


                    }
                    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                    GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                    GridView2.DataBind();

                }

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("ViewState is null");
            }

            //Set Previous Data on Postbacks

            SetPreviousData();
        }


    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        int val = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox63.Text);
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox132");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox133");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox134");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox135");
                    TextBox box5 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox136");
                    TextBox box6 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("TextBox137");
                    TextBox box7 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox138");
                    Button btn = this.GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("btnFooter") as Button;


                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                    box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();
                    box5.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column5"].ToString();
                    box6.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column6"].ToString();
                    box7.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column7"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                    **if (rowIndex+1> val)
                    {
                        btn.Visible = false;
                    }**
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }
```

Here when click that button1 its add new row in gridview. But i have some text box in that aspx page.
when the textbox is show some (int) value, the textbox value and the gridview rows are equal means the button is disable.

Please help.

Comment: use btn.Style.Add("display","none") instead of visible=false

Comment: Thanks for reply sandeep.Can you tell how to wirte that code behind the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code ....

```
 GridView2.ShowFooter = false;
 GridView2.FooterRow.Visible = false;
```